# Rewrite automatically removes backslash if there's more than one?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a very simple url rewriting rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !script.php
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) script.php?q=$1
```

The idea is to have this kind of urls: `http://mywebsite.com/test/http://example.com`
and then send `http://example.com` to the script.php as a query parameter. The problem is that I'm receiving `http:/example.com` instead of `http://example.com`. Also, `http:////example.com` would be sent as `http:/example.com`. What causes this behavior ?

Comment: Please note that `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !script.php` makes no sense in the slightest. `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the hostname of the url, for example `mywebsite.com` in the above example or `127.0.0.1` if you request the website as `http://127.0.0.1/aasdf`. Besides that the second argument is a regular expression. A dot in a regular expression does match a lot of characters including the literal dot. Escape it if you mean to only match a literal dot! (`!script\.php`)

Comment: you're right, so how to match the whole URL ?

Comment: The condition is not required here, since `script.php` is not matched by `^test/(.*)`. If, for some reason, you need to exclude something that is matched by the first argument of RewriteRule, you usually use something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script\.php$`. If you need to match the request as it came in, not as it is rewritten internally through various cycles through your rules, you can match `%{THE_REQUEST}`. This can be useful in situations where you get stuck in an infinite rewriteloop otherwise, not for regular rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache `mod_rewrite` engine converts multiple `///...` into single `/` for pattern matching in `RewriteRule` directive. However if you match it using `RewriteCond` then you can match **multiple** `/`s.

You can use rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+test/+(https?://.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ script.php?q=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser causes this behaviour. It contracts a sequence of `/` into 1 `/`, because it is still essentially a path. `/////` does not change the directory we are in, so we could as well use `/`.

You have two options:

- Change your links to use a query string instead. If you rewrite `test/?q=something` to `script.php?q=something` everything works as expected. You would do the following:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^test/?$ script.php [L]
  ```

  Since you don't alter the query string, the original query string is automatically copied to the new query string.
- Don't make an assumption on how many slashes you will encounter. The url might not look correctly in the url bar of the browser, but if it is just a redirect, it will only be visible for a very short period of time.

  ```
  RewriteRule ^test/(http|https):/+(.*)$ script.php?q=$1://$2
  ```